# ¿Cómo hago para unir dos objetos en un arreglo JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Tengo dos objetos como estos:

```
Object {id: 1234565, name: "NAME PERSON", last_name: "SURNAME PERSON ", id_land: 3, id_charge: 7}

Object {id: 245698, name: "NAME PERSON1, last_name: "SURNAME PERSON 2", id_land: 1, id_charge: 7…}
```

Unirlos en uno sólo de esta manera

```
[Object, Object]
```

Comment: quieres hacer un array de tus objetos? bastaría con `list = [object1, object2]` ?

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder, sí la idea es que los objetos queden en uno para poder recorrerlos con un for, he usado el concat pero no funciona

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define primero un `array`:

```
var arr = [];
```

Y para añadir cada objeto lo haces con un `push`:

```
arr.push(Objeto1);
arr.push(Objeto2);
...
```

Otra buena manera (depende de si creas los objetos ahí mismo) sería añadirlos directamente al `array`:

```
var arr = [];
var len = queryObjetos.results.length;
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    arr.push({
        id: queryObjetos.results[i].id,
        name: queryObjetos.results[i].name,
        last_name: queryObjetos.results[i].last_name,
        id_land: queryObjetos.results[i].id_land,
        id_charge: queryObjetos.results[i].id_charge
    });
}
```

De esta manera ya los tienes todos en la variable `arr`

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta me has ayudado mucho!